# literal_eval and boolean Logic in Python

Tags: python, boolean

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> H = {"('a','b')":1}
>>> x = ('a','b')
>>> str(x)
"('a', 'b')"
>>> list(H.keys())[0]
"('a','b')"
>>> str(x) == list(H.keys())[0]
False
```

Why do I get a False statement? However, when I do

```
>>> x == literal_eval(list(H.keys())[0])
True
```

I get a True statement.

Comment: `list(H.keys())[0]` is also a string, it gives the first element of the list, which is `"('a','b')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests, `str(x)` is `"('a', 'b')"`. Do you notice the space after the comma?

That is enough to explain why the strings are different (one contains a space while the other does not), while the tuples are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nasty. Why is a space being added though?

Comment: @MillFanta: because it is the way the implementors of the tuple builtin class decided to represent a tuple...